# Is there a button to report the moderator?

Tags: support, moderators, moderator-abilities

I've been debugging an issues at a system level of a huge enterprise application, I've seen issues happening with one of the messaging application, the cause of the issue could be several things, a Bridge/Queue/Connection factory/foreign server/concurrency etc., I posted 3 questions over time as I kept narrowing down the issue.

I'm very loyal, i understand the rules of SO. I'm here to find solutions and also help other people. One of the moderator has marked my question duplicate in-spite of me debating that it is not. Is there a button to report saying that the moderator has not done a good job?

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557234/messaging-bridge-is-causing-null-text-message-weblogic-81) here I have clearly specified my question in the title, If the Moderator is not aware of the difference between this question and the other question, can he not ignore? It makes me post the question again, because my question is not answered, it goes on like that in a loop.

Comment: Instead of posting new questions as you narrow down the issue, perhaps you should be editing the original question? Just looking at the one you linked and the one it's marked dupe of, they look like dupes to me... (But I am newer in the programming world, so take that as you will.)

Comment: @Kendra How often do people go to the second page of the specific tag? Yeah, If you know the context of the question I asked, they seem very different. Well, I had put a bounty on one question which i'm unable to delete, so it stayed on.

Comment: Well, it probably depends on the people. I do frequently. But if you edit your question, it becomes "active" and shows up in the "active" tab on the main site, or on whichever tag's "active" tab that your question is in. So editing does still bump it up, and help you get answers.

Comment: *"It makes me post the question again, because my question is not answered, it goes on like that in a loop."* ... no it doesn't. Because if you do, that will end up in more trouble than it's worth. Furthermore, by asking what seem to be follow up questions or at the very least tightly linked questions while others are as of yet unanswered, you're not creating an ideal environment for your questions.

Comment: Could you perhaps list all questions that are part of your group of questions on the same topic? [This for example isn't a question at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536828/javax-jms-jmsexception-failed-to-enlist-the-transaction).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the topic, but these two questions certainly seem to be duplicates: in [Messaging bridge is causing null text message - Weblogic 81](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557234/messaging-bridge-is-causing-null-text-message-weblogic-81) you ask, *"what could be possibly wrong if we are getting TextMessage object with content null?"* and in [What causes a JMS Message sent as Null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518959/what-causes-a-jms-message-sent-as-null) you ask, *"What are the reasons for the JMS message to be sent to the consumer as NULL(text property)?"*

Comment: Zeus it will not go on in an endless loop though. Too many closed questions and you're out (of priviliges).

Comment: This is the problem with stackoverflow. It doesn't allow for real communication. It's run by moderated by pretentious aholes.

Answer (score 17):

> I posted 3 questions over time as I kept narrowing down the issue.

I guess we're talking about

- [Concurrent JMS messages cause NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455263/concurrent-jms-messages-cause-null)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518959/what-causes-a-jms-message-sent-as-null
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557234/messaging-bridge-is-causing-null-text-message-weblogic-81

If so, I have to say I would see those later two as duplicates of the first one as well. They all revolve around the same issue. You may have narrowed down the issue over time, but I see no evidence of that. Furthermore, if you narrow down an issue, use that information to clarify your original question. It still has no answer except your own

> I"m surprised that no one was able to figure this out. Solution is to use MDBs instead of using plain java classes.

which I guess was incorrect, given that you later on removed it. So if anything, clarify the original. From the comments I seem to gather you think that would be a lost cause anyway, but any edit bumps a question and will give it renewed attention.

> One of the moderator has marked my question duplicate in-spite of me debating that it is not. Is there a button to report saying that the moderator has not done a good job?

[@Cupcake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/456814/cupcake) explained in [his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262534/488657) what you can do to report a moderator you think is abusing his privileges. That you could do, but it's not the route I would take in this particular case.

> If the Moderator is not aware of the difference between this question and the other question, can he not ignore?

No. Because that simply isn't the situation. The moderator isn't aware of the difference because the questions don't seem to be different. It's not the moderator who should ignore them, it's you who should make it obvious they are different if they really are.

Keep in mind that we're not following along with your process. We're not on your train of thought and can't read your mind. You can flag or report moderators all you want, but that's not going to improve your questions. And assuming for a while that you really tried to ask different questions, then question quality/clarity is where your problem is at.

> It makes me post the question again, because my question is not answered, it goes on like that in a loop.

No. Don't post questions again because they aren't answered or because they are closed. That will only get those questions closed as well and - if you persist - you might end up with a ban. So don't. Ask one question, clarify it, get an answer for it, and if after that you still have additional questions to ask, ask a new question.

Answer (score 14):

### Reporting Moderators

According to [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges/28869#28869):

> If you have a dispute with a diamond moderator your options are:
>
> - Send a message to the Stack Exchange team via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page with your complaint and links to the
>     questions/answers.
> - Flag for moderator attention and request a second moderator to have a look.

That being said, just because you report a moderator for what you believe is poor performance or misconduct in his or her duties, that **does not mean that other people will agree with you**, and take action because of it.

Also note, as pointed out in the linked Meta Stack Exchange answer above, that if you want a **quick** response, it is better to try to get in touch with another moderator, rather than try to escalate the issue to the Stack Exchange team